# From Python List delete specific element of Last and First character

Tags: python, list

I want to delete Last And first element of List of elements

Ex:

```
List = ['SGAAG_Anhaenger_',  '_Anhaenger_', '_Test_Data']
```

From the above list  i want to delete in first element last character and  First and Last character for 2nd Element and first character for 3rd element if last/first character is "_".

Comment: From what I understand: `List[1:-1]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like what you actually want to do is strip off leading and trailing `'_'` characters.

```
>>> lis = ['SGAAG_Anhaenger_',  '_Anhaenger_', '_Test_Data']
>>> [s.strip('_') for s in lis]
['SGAAG_Anhaenger', 'Anhaenger', 'Test_Data']
```